# After In-App Purchase, viewWillAppear Loads The Purchased Item Multiple Times

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I'm having trouble with my In-App Purchases. Upon leaving the MasterViewController (where the IAP items are listed and bought) I come to the ViewController which in the viewDidLoad it checks for purchased items, but I also have a viewWillAppear checking for purchased items and unlocking those purchased items right when the ViewController is loaded.

The problem is, every time the ViewController is reloaded or refreshed, left and then gone back to, the viewWillAppear checks for purchased items and unlocks the items again, which in my case the purchased items come from javascript files, which happens to load the JS multiple times, cluttering the app with the same IAP item over and over again.

For instance, if you purchased 'Bookmarks', every time you reload the ViewController, you'll get another 'Bookmarks' tool, over and over again.

How do I get it so that the IAP is loaded only one time?

My viewWillAppear looks like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
// Check To See If The Uniques IAP Has Been Paid For
if (![[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SHOW_UNIQUES_KEY] isEqualToString: @"YES"]){ // NEW CODE
    // Code to show bookmarks

} else {
    NSString *jsString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Uniques" withExtension:@"js"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [viewWeb stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];    }
NSLog(@"Shows uniques?: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SHOW_UNIQUES_KEY]);

// Check To See If The PL Numbers IAP Has Been Paid For
if (![[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SHOW_PORTAL_LEVEL_KEY] isEqualToString: @"YES"]){ // NEW CODE
    // Code to show bookmarks

} else {
    NSString *jsString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"PortalLevel" withExtension:@"js"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [viewWeb stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];    }
NSLog(@"Shows portal levels?: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SHOW_PORTAL_LEVEL_KEY]);

// Check To See If The PN IAP Has Been Paid For
if (![[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SHOW_PORTALS_KEY] isEqualToString: @"YES"]){ // NEW CODE
    // Code to show bookmarks

} else {
    NSString *jsString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"PortalNames" withExtension:@"js"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [viewWeb stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];    }
NSLog(@"Shows portal names?: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SHOW_PORTALS_KEY]);

// Check To See If The Bookmarks IAP Has Been Paid For
if (![[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SHOW_BOOKMARKS_KEY] isEqualToString: @"YES"]){ // NEW CODE
    // Code to show bookmarks

} else {
    NSString *jsString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"bookmarks" withExtension:@"js"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [viewWeb stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];    }
NSLog(@"Shows bookmarks?: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SHOW_BOOKMARKS_KEY]);

// Check To See If The Poke A Bowl Ad Has Been Paid For
if (![[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SHOW_ADS_KEY] isEqualToString: @"No"]){ // NEW CODE
    // Code to show ads
    _PokeABowlAd.hidden = NO;

} else {
    _PokeABowlAd.hidden = YES;
}
NSLog(@"Shows ads?: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SHOW_ADS_KEY]);
}
```

Comment: Is your code to show bookmarks (that isn't shown) adding a subview - something like this: [self.view addSubview: something]?

Comment: I'm try to unlock a JavaScript file. The JavaScript file is the bookmarks tool. The only problem is, every time the view controller loads or gets called, the JavaScript file gets called again. It keeps loading multiple bookmark tools on my View Controller.

Comment: The nss  string that says URLforResource bookmarks is the JS file.

Comment: How would I call the saved IAP when switching back to the ViewController from MasterViewController instead of using ViewWillAppear which calls the code more than needed.

Comment: Or maybe a better question is, how would I unlock the IAP right after it has been purchased? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you should do is make it so that each one is called at most once. You should use NSUserDefaults to accomplish this. Do something like this:

Put this in your AppDelegate.m:

```
//One new key for each IAP - put at the top of the AppDelegate.m and VC.m
#define IAP_FIRST_USED @"IAP 1 Used"
...
#define IAP_LAST_USED @"IAP X Used"
```

and

```
// In applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions, should be the first method listed

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: @"No" forKey: IAP_FIRST_USED];
...
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: @"No" forKey: IAP_LAST_USED];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

And then in the VC.m modify viewWillAppear to be like this (this is an example of what just the first IAP should look like):

```
// Check To See If The PL Numbers IAP Has Been Paid For
if (![[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SHOW_PORTAL_LEVEL_KEY] isEqualToString: @"YES"]){ // NEW CODE


   // NEW CODE BEGINS HERE

   if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:IAP_FIRST_USED] isEqualToString: @"No"]){
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: @"Yes" forKey: IAP_FIRST_USED];
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];  
   // Code to show bookmarks



   // End of code to show bookmarks
   // NEW CODE ENDS HERE

   }
} else {
    NSString *jsString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"PortalLevel" withExtension:@"js"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [viewWeb stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];    
}
```

Also remember to include the define statements in VC.m

Comment: I just tried that and it keeps loading the Bookmarks tool javascript whenever I switch from ViewController - MasterViewController and back to ViewController.

Comment: Have you tried switching which code goes into the new code I put? It looks like it may be the code in the else statement that is calling the javascript, not the part after //Code to show bookmarks

Comment: I just moved the code in the else statement to //Code to show bookmarks and now after IAP it does not show/unlock at all. Only when you close the app and reopen it still.

Comment: Remove the ! in the first if statement

Comment: That worked! Now do I have to create a new set of define keys for each IAP? If so, what would be an example of the next two if the first two are #define IAP_FIRST_USED @"IAP 1 Used"
...
#define IAP_LAST_USED @"IAP X Used"

Comment: They can be literally anything as long as they aren't the same as another define statement. You should probably do SHOW_PORTAL_USED_KEY for the first one

Comment: Do the @"IAP 1 Used" and @"IAP X Used" have to be different?

Comment: The KEYs are equal to the NSString that come after them. You don't really need the define statement, it's just good practice since it improves readability.

Comment: I just doubled everything and changed the define keys to #define IAP_FIRST_SHOW_ADS_KEY_USED @"IAP 2 Used"
#define IAP_LAST_SHOW_ADS_KEY_USED @"IAP B Used" in hopes of hiding the Ad banner. Where the NSString is i put _PokeABowl.hidden = YES; but the banner did not dissapear. Any idea?

Comment: Don't remove the ! from that if statement

Comment: If I add the ! to that if statement, the ad is already hidden when the app is launched, even without an IAP.

Comment: It sounds like you have the wrong key there then. When you first launch the app the key value should be nil (undefined) so that if the ! was there then the if statement would be true and the ad would not appear.

Comment: Is it ok if I use the original statement? I'm sure it is hiding the ad banner every time the view will appear but it works... what do you think? // Check To See If The Poke A Bowl Ad Has Been Paid For
    if (![[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SHOW_ADS_KEY] isEqualToString: @"No"]){ // NEW CODE
        // Code to show ads
        _PokeABowlAd.hidden = NO;
        
    } else {
        _PokeABowlAd.hidden = YES;
    }
    NSLog(@"Shows ads?: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SHOW_ADS_KEY]);

Comment: Ok Awesome! You're a genius! I think I'm ready to move onto the next and hopefully final question :p  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32014674/displaying-in-app-purchase-detail-description