# How Do I Display The Description Of An In-App Purchase Item?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a MasterViewController that shows a list of In-App Purchases in a table view. Whenever the table view cell is clicked, it presents my DetailViewController but it doesn't present the localized detail description for that In-App Purchase item. Is there a way so that depending on which IAP item was pressed in the tableview cell, it will present that IAP item's description in the DVC?

[image]

Here is my MVC.m:

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "RageIAPHelper.h"
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

@interface MasterViewController () {
NSArray *_products;
NSNumberFormatter * _priceFormatter;
}
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
[self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:backButtonItem];

self.title = @"Settings";

self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(reload) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self reload];
[self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];

_priceFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[_priceFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[_priceFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Restore" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(restoreTapped:)];

}

- (void)restoreTapped:(id)sender {
[[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(productPurchased:) name:IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)productPurchased:(NSNotification *)notification {

NSString * productIdentifier = notification.object;
[_products enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(SKProduct * product, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:productIdentifier]) {
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        *stop = YES;
    }
}];

}

- (void)reload {
_products = nil;
[self.tableView reloadData];
[[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *products) {
    if (success) {
        _products = products;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
}];
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return _products.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

SKProduct * product = (SKProduct *) _products[indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = product.localizedTitle;
[_priceFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [_priceFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];

if ([[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] productPurchased:product.productIdentifier]) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    cell.accessoryView = nil;
} else {
    UIButton *buyButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    buyButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 72, 37);
    [buyButton setTitle:@"Buy" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    buyButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    [buyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buyButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.accessoryView = buyButton;
}

return cell;
}

- (void)buyButtonTapped:(id)sender {

UIButton *buyButton = (UIButton *)sender;
SKProduct *product = _products[buyButton.tag];

NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);
[[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] buyProduct:product];

}

@end
```

And here is my DetailViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *detailDescriptionLabel;
@end
```

And my DetailViewController.m:

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()
- (void)configureView;
@end

@implementation DetailViewController

#pragma mark - Managing the detail item

- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
    _detailItem = newDetailItem;

    // Update the view.
    [self configureView];
}
}

- (void)configureView
{
// Update the user interface for the detail item.

if (self.detailItem) {
    self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = [self.detailItem description];
    _detailDescriptionLabel.text = @"Please enable in app purchase in your settings";

}
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
[self configureView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add this method your MasterVC.m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    DetailViewController *dest = [segue destinationViewController];
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)sender;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    SKProduct *product = (SKProduct *) _products[indexPath.row];
    dest.detailText = product.localizedDescription;

}
```

In DetailVC.h add:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *detailText;
```

In DetailVC.m add:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = detailText;

}
```

Make sure you import your DetailViewController.h at the top of your MasterVC.m file.

Comment: This didn't seem to do anything :/

Comment: Comment out the contents of configureView in your DetailVC

Comment: I went ahead and did that and still get nothing.

Comment: Are you using a push segue to get to the DetailVC from the MasterVC?

Comment: I was not. I made it a push segue and i get two notifications that say Push segues are depreciated in ios 8.0 and later.

Comment: Oh I meant the segue that replaces a push segue, a show segue

Comment: Ok. Will you put an NSLog into prepareForSegue and let me know if that is actually getting called?

Comment: 2015-08-14 11:27:26.943 GPS[1572:217402] Shows prepareForSegue?: (null)

Comment: What did you put in for the value that's printing null?

Comment: NSLog(@"Shows prepareForSegue?: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SHOW_SEGUE_KEY]);

Comment: Ok so look at the three changes I made: I changed the last line of the prepareForSegue and added something for both DetailVC.h and .m

Comment: Ok! The DVC is now responding and changing the label to the IAP item Title name. Any way to change it to read/import the IAP item Description?

Comment: So just change the cell.textLabel.text part of the line dest.detailText = cell.textLabel.text;
 to whatever you want.

Comment: I add     cell.textLabel.text = product.localizedDescription;
to the UITableViewCell underneath     cell.textLabel.text = product.localizedTitle;
 but now when I load the MVC, it shows the description instead of title, and the DVC now shows the description but i need the MVC to show the title.

Comment: I get an error message saying "Property localizedDescription not found on object of type id"

Comment: It's a breath of fresh air! :D I'll never forget the work you put into this!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87039/discussion-between-creagen-and-wmios).